# ¿Como valido que un campo entero en un formulario no este vacío?

Tags: android-studio, firebase, kotlin

Estoy haciendo peticiones a Firebase desde android studio, de momento funciona las solicitudes POST, pero al validar campos vacíos, el campo edad hace que la app se caiga, ocupo saber como validar que un editText que recibe enteros, no quede en null o vacio ya que ese es el problema, de momento las demás validaciones sirven. Edad es el unico campo entero en mi modelo.

class FirestoreViewModel: ViewModel()  {

```
val firestoreUseCase = FirestoreUseCase()

fun crearUsuario(nombre:String,apellido:String,edad:Int,sexo:String){
    firestoreUseCase.setearUsuarioFirestore(nombre,apellido,edad,sexo)
}
```

}

//funcion POST para crear usuario

fun crearUsuario(){

```
    btn_enviardatos.setOnClickListener {
        val nombre = etxt_nombre.text.toString().trim()
        val apellido = etxt_apellido.text.toString().trim()
        val edad = etxt_edad.text.toString().toInt()
        val sexo = etxt_sexo.text.toString().trim()
        if (nombre.isNotEmpty() && apellido.isNotEmpty() && edad > 0  && sexo.isNotEmpty()){
            viewModel.crearUsuario(nombre,apellido,edad,sexo)
            etxt_nombre.setText("")
            etxt_apellido.setText("")
            etxt_edad.setText("")
            etxt_sexo.setText("")
        }else{
         Toast.makeText(this,"Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evita el `toInt()` al principio y hace lo siguiente en la validacion

```
val edad = etxt_edad.text.toString()

if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(edad)) {
// tu codigo , aca podes usar edad.toInt()
}
```

Recorda que no puede ser null el editText si lo encontraste con el `findViewById`, y recorda que aunque el `inputType` sea de number, siempre recibis un string como dato, luego lo convertis a lo que necesites, pero tenes que chequearlo que no este vacio

Comment: Funcionó,  muchas gracias. Estoy aprendiendo a programar Android solo, entonces aún no tengo los conceptos básicos afianzados, pero es bueno saber estos detalles!

Answer (score 0):

Evita convertir texto a Integer directamente, en vez de eso, puedes hacer un try- catch, y en caso de error reaccionar cambiando el resultado.

Ejemplo:

```
// si estás asignando un valor a un objeto que creaste anteriormente, lo mejor es rechazar el cambio si 
// el número indicado inválido o dejarlo como 0
 val valor_anterior_del_campo_o_cero = 22;

btn_enviardatos.setOnClickListener {
...
  val edad: Int;
   try {
     edad = etxt_edad.text.toString().toInt()
   } catch(err: Exception) {
      Log.e("parser", "Un error al convertir string a integer")
      edad = valor_anterior_del_campo_o_cero
   }
 ....

}
```

Tambien puedes verificar que el string no este vacio:

```
if (etxt_edad.text.toString() == "") {
  edad = 0
  //esta edad parece esta mal
}
else ...
```

Otro comentario es que trates de cambiar el InputType en el editText si estás programando para android, asi te evitas algunas sorpresas sobre lo que el usuario puede ingresar.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta aceptada es correcta pero yo creo que quedaria mejor asi:

```
val edad = etxt_edad.text.toString().toIntOrNull() ?: 0
```

Si el string se puede convertir a int lo va asignar a edad si no edad igual a 0